# Umbraco Contour: Changing Subject line to different dictionary items

Tags: email, umbraco, umbraco-contour

I having a serious issue with Umbraco Contour. I wish to send on 2 emails on submission with 2 different subjects with information gathered from the umbraco dictionary. The form and the email response works fine, but its just the subject line.

Heres example of what I want to send to the client.

[image]

So for other email I would just change client to host so its like
"Email Host Subject" instead of "Email Client Subject"

What it renders on the email is the "[#Email Client Subject]" I have tried different alternatives but no success, same results..

Comment: Ask this on our.umbraco.org and see what people say there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to omit the square brackets when declaring the dictionary item e.g.

```
#Email Client Subject
```

Anything after the # is treated as the dictionary key.

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-pro/contour/15992-bracket-syntax-for-dictionary-item